# Cannot login to MySQL when MySQL service is running

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, windows-server-2008-r2

I can't login to MySQL when the service is running. But when I stop the service and run MySQL via executing `"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqld.exe"` in CMD, I can login to MySQL via phpmyadmin but there's no database there (except the default databases)

When the service is running I can't login via phpmyadmin or MySQL CMD.

I tried to reset my password using [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) article but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from lack of `--defaults-file` when I'm resetting my password. (or wrong path of the file since I tried to run my command with and without this option) I found the path of defaults-file and by adding this to mysqld and resetting password the problem solved.